# C# Hollow rectangle using Enumerable.Repeat()

Tags: c#, for-loop, enumerable

I was given the assignment to create a hollow rectangle using Enumerable.Repeat instead of nested loops. I've done it like this.

```
string str;
int rows = 5;
int cols = 15;

for (int i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
{
    if (i == 1 || i == rows)
    {
        str = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat("*", cols));
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
    else
    {
        str = string.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(" ", cols - 2));
        str = string.Concat("*", str, "*");
        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
```

It works just fine, but the hollow part I've designed doesn't seem like *THE WAY* to go if you know what I mean... What would be the most efficient way to go? Excluding the use of StringBuilder.

Comment: How about you use `Enumerable.Repeat` to create 1 line, then use `Enumerable.Repeat` again, on that 1 line to create N lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache the lines and `Join` them:

```
 string top = new string('*', cols);
 string body = "*" + new string(' ', cols - 2) + "*";

 string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
   top, 
   string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
     .Repeat(body, rows - 2)),
   top);

 Consol.Write(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

In this case, there is a string constructor that is a better choice. Here is just one segment from the original to demonstrate:

```
if (i == 1 || i == rows)
{
    str = string.Concat(new string('*', cols));
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}
```

Additionally, you can simplify the whole thing by putting the top and bottom rows outside of the loop:

```
int rows = 5;
int cols = 15;

 Console.WriteLine(new string('*', cols);
 foreach(string line in Enumerable.Repeat("*".Concat(new string(' ', cols-2)).Concat("*"), rows-2))
 {
      Console.WriteLine(line);
 }
 Console.WriteLine(new string('*', cols);
```

Comment: @Servy That was just to help fit in context with his previous code.

Comment: The whole point of the exercise is to use concat and Enumerable.Repeat...

Comment: @DaniRashba If you're writing to the console, Concat() is a poor choice here.